# sql server linked tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

suppose I have three tables (table1, table2, table3) linked to a master table tableM.

I have primary key ID in the tableM and foreign key ID in other tables.

suppose I insert a row in tableM, will other tables get inserted a row automatically? Or do I have to write a sp by my own?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: As previous answer correctly said: Rows do not get inserted automatically.

Is PK ID in TableM Identity? is this whats struggled you? you can store this value like this `set @var=@@IDENTITY` and use it as FK in other tables.

Comment: I recommend using `scope_identity()` over `@@IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rows do not get inserted automatically.  You have to insert a row into your master table first, and then insert rows into your FK tables afterwards to avoid a FK constraint error.

Comment: in this case, is it a good way to use computed columns for ID?

Answer (score 2):

No, rows are not inserted automatically. Additionally, the `INSERT` statement could not possibly include columns from these child tables, so even if a row were inserted automatically it could not include data.

You will need to either write a stored procedure (recommended if these child rows are required by the business logic) or simply insert into tables as necessary.

Comment: in this case, is it a good way to use computed columns for ID in child tables in original design?